# SEVERE: Running with Java class version 53.0, but 52.0 is required error with Jenkins through command prompt as "java -jar jenkins.war"

Tags: java, jenkins

I am automation engineer i have deployed my build on the Jenkins using maven, I want to when scripts are executed then the browser should open.  I searched on it some peoples says my me Run the Jenkins war file through cmd prompt when I am trying to Run the Jenkins through command prompt as:

```
java -jar Jenkins.war
```

Then the system generates an error as follows:

```
SEVERE: Running with Java class version 53.0, but 52.0 is required error
```

Anyone have any idea how I can fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel The dup target of this question does points us to the main issue of **Unsupported major.minor** but none of the _Answers_ speaks about the solution from **Jenkins** point of view to enable **Jenkins** to run on _Java 10_ and _Java 11_ versions using the command line flags `--enable-future-java`. Please consider reopening the Question.

Comment: @Newcontributor done

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: The error message here would be better as actual text in the question. Searchable and copyable.

Comment: @jdv Looks good now?

Comment: Sure, but you also might want to run gradle with the options that show more of the error.

Answer (score 10):

This error message...

```
SEVERE: Running with Java class version 53.0, but 52.0 is required.
```

...implies that you have tried to initialize **Jenkins**  on a system which is using **java class version 53.0** which stands for **Java 9**.

As per the **Jenkins** documentation on [Java requirements](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) the following are mentioned:

- **Java 8** is the **ONLY** supported *runtime environment*, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are supported.
- Older versions of Java are not supported.
- **Java 9** is not supported.
- **Java 10** and **Java 11** preview support is available.
- Support of these versions is available through custom packages
- [Running Jenkins with Java 10 and 11 (experimental support)](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/06/17/running-jenkins-with-java10-11/) page provides guidelines about running Jenkins with these versions.
- These requirements apply to all components of the Jenkins system including Jenkins master, all types of agents, CLI clients, and other components.

---

### Solution

There are two possible solutions as follows:

- You can downgrade your *Jenkins* host *JRE* to *Java 8* version and initiate **Jenkins** as follows:

  ```
  ${JAVA8_HOME}/bin/java -jar jenkins.war
  ```
- You can upgrade your *Jenkins* host *JRE* to *Java 10* or *Java 11* version and initiate **Jenkins** along with the **`--enable-future-java`** flag as follows:

  ```
  ${JAVA10_HOME}/bin/java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java
  ```

---

### Running Jenkins (without Docker)

**Java 10**

- Download Jenkins WAR for 2.127 or above (or build the [**experimental branch**](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/java10-support))
- Run the Jenkins WAR file with the following command:

  ```
  ${JAVA10_HOME}/bin/java --add-modules java.xml.bind -jar jenkins.war \
      --enable-future-java --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins
  ```

**Java 11**

- Download Jenkins WAR for 2.127 or above (or build the [**experimental branch**](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/java11-support))
- Download the following libraries to the same directory as jenkins.war

  - [**jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar**](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar) (save as jaxb-api.jar)
  - [**jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar**](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar) (save as jaxb-core.jar)
  - [**jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar**](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0.1/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar) (save as jaxb-impl.jar)
  - [**javax.activation v.1.2.0**](https://github.com/javaee/activation/releases/download/JAF-1_2_0/javax.activation.jar) (save as javax.activation.jar)
- Run the Jenkins WAR file with the following command:

  ```
  ${JAVA11_HOME}/bin/java \
      -p jaxb-api.jar:javax.activation.jar --add-modules java.xml.bind,java.activation \
      -cp jaxb-core.jar:jaxb-impl.jar \
      -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins
  ```

---

### trivia

As per [Java class file - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) following are the major version number of the class file format being used:

```
Java SE 11 = 55
Java SE 10 = 54
Java SE 9 = 53
Java SE 8 = 52
Java SE 7 = 51
Java SE 6.0 = 50
Java SE 5.0 = 49
JDK 1.4 = 48
JDK 1.3 = 47
JDK 1.2 = 46
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Comment: Thanks Your dedication , i had upgrade my jre-10.0.2 but still  i am facing the error .jenkins required java 8 but you are running 10.0.2

Comment: @mudassarmunir Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: thanks: i have already installed Jenkins Jenkins-2.138.1 , above mentioned files i has placed in the same directory of Jenkins war, can you tell me how i can run the commands?

Comment: I have already provided the command there within the `Running Jenkins (without Docker) - Java 10` section

Answer (score 5):

```
java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java
```

Comment: Please add some information into the answer. Just posting a command is not a good answer as such.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Java 15 on my system. To run Jenkins with Java 15, please execute the below command.

D:\Selenium\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=9090 --enable-future-java

Change path to your war file.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is supported java version are 8,11 . jenkins not supported older versions and java 9,10,12 and 13 too , you have to downgrade java version to 8 or 11

Comment: This was also my issue. Check the Jenkins error log for details.

Comment: are you ok now ? any issues ?

Comment: Installing an older version of java and attach it to Jenkins indeed solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install JDK8 and set system environment variable 'path' to JDK8 /bin/ folder

Comment: That means, you move back to Java 8. My Solution says that you can use Java 10 but instead of War you need to use Jenkins.exe solution

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Jenkins WAR support is compatible up to Java 8.

You are using 9.0.4, Which is higher version from Jenkins recommendation

You can still use Jenkins, With Windows service: [Click Here to Download](https://jenkins.io/download/thank-you-downloading-windows-installer-stable)

Comment: Thanks Your dedication , i had upgrade my jre-10.0.2 but still i am facing the error .jenkins required java 8 but you are running 10.0.2